# Coordinates of box of annotations in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I get the coordinates of the box displayed in the following plot?

[image]

```
fig, ax = subplots()
x = ax.annotate('text', xy=(0.5, 0), xytext=(0.0,0.7), 
                ha='center', va='bottom',
                bbox=dict(boxstyle='round', fc='gray', alpha=0.5),
                arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->', color='blue'))
```

I tried to inspect the properties of this object, but I couldn't find something suited to this purpose. There is a property called `get_bbox_patch()` which could be on the right track, however, I get results in a different coordinate system (or associated to a different property)

```
y = x.get_bbox_patch()
y.get_width()
63.265625
```

Thanks  a lot!

Comment: I suggest you read this: http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html  What units do you want the coordinates in?

Comment: Already did. I didn't help a lot because it shows how to transform coordinates to different reference systems, but not width or height. I think I want "data coordinates".

Comment: Suspect that the width is in display coordinates, widths are just the difference between two points, so if you can do coordinates, you can do widths. The box is centered where you put it, you just need grab the transform you want (they come packed with their inverses).

Comment: There are many pair of points that give the same width, so if I choose one pair randomly and transform it, I'm going to get an equally arbitrary coordinate.

Comment: And you do know you can set mpl to not show that gray background on the axes right?

Comment: What you mean? grid=True?

Comment: no, I mean the gray background that makes it look like an excel plot

Comment: Oh, that's part of this configuration file: https://gist.github.com/huyng/816622. It's supposed to be similar to ggplot :-P.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ax.figure.canvas.draw()
bbox = x.get_window_extent()
```

will return a [`Bbox`](http://matplotlib.org/devel/transformations.html#matplotlib.transforms.Bbox) object for your text in display units (the `draw` is necessary so that the text is rendered and actually has a display size). You can then use the transforms to convert it to which ever coordinate system you want.
Ex

```
bbox_data = ax.transData.inverted().transform(bbox)
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be right. Did you notice that the output coordinates don't really match the xytext coordinates? They seem to be proportional, though. For example,  xytext=(0.0,1.0) gives [[-0.11196657  0.83225806]
 [-0.06034526  0.87258065]]

Comment: I get back `[[-0.02608367  1.        ]
 [ 0.02608367  1.03385417]]`.  Remember this is the bounding box, so it will depend on your `ha` and `va` settings.

Comment: You're right. However, I still get 0.8 in the y coordinate. Can you add the code you tried? Maybe there is an extra argument that needs to be considered.

Comment: Uhm... now I'm getting an error saying "RuntimeError: Cannot get window extent w/o renderer" when running "x.get_widow_extent()." in a single cell (in Ipython notebook)

Comment: I think I got... I wasn't drawing the canvas. After running this: fig.canvas.draw(), I don't get errors and the coordinates are the same as yours. Can you confirm this?

Comment: Great, thanks for all your help. By the way, there is a small typo in `get_widow_extent()`.

Comment: For me neither `fig.canvas.draw()` or `plt.draw()` resolved the "RuntimeError: Cannot get window extent w/o renderer" error, but only `fig.savefig('something.pdf')`. After doing the following work, I save it again.

Answer (score 1):

To your questions there is also a a pre-question:

- When you write `How can I get the coordinates of the box displayed in the following plot?`, which coordinate system you mean?

By default `annotate` is done using `xytext = None, defaults to xy, and if textcoords = None, defaults to xycoords`.

Since you didn't specify the coordinate system. Your annotation is on the default system. You could specify the data coordinates, which for some purposes is good enough:

```
x = ax.annotate('text', xy=(0.5, 0), xytext=(0.0,0.7), 
                ha='center', va='bottom', textcoords='data', xycoords="data",
                bbox=dict(boxstyle='round', fc='gray', alpha=0.5),
                arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->', color='blue'))
```

To find the coordinate system, you can do:

```
In [39]: x.xycoords
Out[39]: 'data'
```

and to get the coordinates:

```
In [40]: x.xytext
Out[40]: (0.0, 0.7)

In [41]: x.xy
Out[41]: (0.5, 0)
```

P.S. not directly related, but the output is from [IPython](http://ipython.org/), if you still don't use it, it can boost how you develop in Python and use matplotlib. Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks. As I said, data coordinates are fine. I can't see how to obtain coordinates of the box based on xytext, though. Actually, I had already done this while testing different properties. Yes, I use the Ipython notebook all the time. Have you tried the qtconsole as a scratch pad?